# Should I delete a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

So I've got to do a project, where I need to implement an `array`, a `list`, `binary heap`, `binary tree` and a `red-black tree`and then measure their performance, compare them and draw some conclusions. Now, the rules are like this:

1. Got to use C/C++
2. Cannot use `std::` (only `cout`, maybe a `string`), `Boost`

So I am on a first step, implementing an array. It looks like this:

`array.h`

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
class array
{
    int elements;
    int *table;
public:
    array();
    array(int *t, int n);
    int size() const;
    int *get() const;
};
```

`array.cpp`

```
#include "array.h"    

array::array(int *t, int n) : elements(n), table(new int[elements])
{   
    memcpy(table, t, elements * sizeof(int));
}

int array::size() const
{
    return elements;
}

int *array::get() const
{
    return table;
}
```

The program basically has a menu-like structure, using simple `switch` and 5 different menus for 5 conteners. Now, I have to implement deleting/adding elements, printing out the array, etc. I have a code that will print out the array in one line:

```
int *p = myArray.get();
int s = myArray.size();
std::cout << "[";
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.size(); i++)
{
    if (s - i == 1) std::cout << *(p + i) << "]" << '\n';
    else std::cout << *(p + i) << ", ";
}
delete p;
```

The thing I am curious about is the last line I wrote. Firstly I didn't use `delete`, cuz nowhere in this block of code exists a `new` operator. But then I thought, yeah well, it prolly causes memory leaks, and I've added that line. Works both ways. And my question is: Which one is correct? In this situation do I have or should I delete a `pointer`?

Comment: You DID use new.  It's in the table member of the array constructor.

Comment: Okay, there I did. But doesnt `int *p = myArray.get();` just copy a pointer, not the whole array?

Comment: since you allocated with new [] in the ctor, you probably want to free with delete [] in the dtor of your array class.

Comment: Okay, but nowhere here I use dtor, I just want to get the pointer to my array, use it, and then I don't know if I should delete that pointer

Comment: You should create a dtor, and delete[] table; from there.  If you don't, you have a memory leak.  The OS will clean this up when the program exits, but it's terrible practice to allow that to happen.

Comment: @Frynio Instead of `get()`, you should implement a `begin()`, `end()` and an `operator[]`, and if you want your buffer to delete at the right time, use `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: @JGroven Okay, will do, but should I leave `delete p` here?

@GuillaumeRacicot I cannot use anything from `std::`

Comment: @Frynio, if you delete with the dtor, you should remove delete p;.

Comment: But should I call dtor here?

Comment: You don't delete pointers, you delete the things they point to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any time you use `new` (or `new[]`), you need a matching `delete` (or `delete[]`), so you need to delete the array pointed to by `array::table` somewhere.  `array`'s destructor is the usual place to do it, since `array` owns that data.  That way your `array`'s data will be deleted whenever the `array` goes out of scope.  Keep in mind the [rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) though.  If your class owns some resource, you should override the default copy constructor, copy operator, and destructor.

You seem to misunderstand what `delete` does.  `delete` deletes dynamically allocated objects, not pointers.  After doing `int *p = myArray.get();`, you have the following situation:

```
+-----------+
|  myArray  |
| +-------+ |  +-------+
| | table | |  | p     |
| +---+---+ |  +-------+
+-----|-----+  |
      | +------+
      | |
     +v-v-----------------------+
     |       allocated data     |
     +--------------------------+
```

When you call `delete[] table` or `delete[] p`, you'll end up with the following:

```
+-----------+
|  myArray  |
| +-------+ |  +-------+
| | table | |  | p     |
| +---+---+ |  +-------+
+-----|-----+  |
      | +------+
      | |
      v v

      Nothing here anymore, but the pointers still point here.
```

The array pointed to by both `myArray.table` and `p` is gone, so the behavior when calling `delete[]` on a pointer that points to the memory that used to hold that array is undefined.

Comment: Okay, I've added the destructor which simply does `delete[] table`. Should I leave the `delete p` line here?

Comment: No, you should never `delete` the same object more than once.

Comment: But `int *p = myArray.get();` just copies the pointer, right? If I delete it, then my `*table` is still safe, doesn't it?

Comment: Exactly, you just copied a pointer and then deleted the object it pointed to.  You end up with a pointer pointing to nothing.

Comment: `delete p` deletes `table`?

Comment: No, `delete[] p` deletes _the object pointed to by `table`_ because `p` points to the same object as `table`.  (The behavior of `delete p` is undefined behavior because `p` and `table` both point to the first element of an a array created with `new[]`)

Comment: So table will exist, but there will be random values on the stack?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137010/discussion-between-frynio-and-miles-budnek).

Answer (score 3):

'Deleting' a pointer will free the memory that it points to regardless if it is a copy or the 'original'. This is because it simply holds a memory address (or a copy of the memory address) and not the actual memory.

Also when you access freed memory you can't guarantee that the data that is returned to you is the data you wanted/expected, so you should only do delete pointers in the destructor of their owner or when you are sure that you won't need them anymore.

And you when using `new` or `new[]` you should always use the correct `delete` or `delete[]` counterpart.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider the ownership of your dynamic resource.

The ownership means someone has responsibility to free it when no one will use it anymore. If your `array` create the resource, you better let it free it by his own in destructor. The one created the resource be the owner naturally.

If you intend to let someone outside get the pointer, the `int* p`, and free it, `delete p`(should be `delete [] p`), that is you give the ownership to `p`. Your `array` need to know it does not own it anymore, and not allowed to delete it by `array`.

When the ownership is clearly explicit, the resource will have less chance to be leaked or double deleted.

BTW, here are some tips for your code.

- `p = new T` pair with `delete p`; `p = new T[]` pair with `delete p []`
- Prefer use `size_t` to represent count of element.
- Passing `int* t` can have the constness like `const int* t`. It does not need `t` be mutable .