# Pointers Reassignment

Tags: c++, pointers

cpp newbie here

If I initiate a two pointers, like

```
int* a = new int(1);
int* b = new int(2);
```

and I want to give the pointer `a` a new value, shoud I delete its current value before?

In other words, what is more correct, doing

```
int* a = new int(1);
int* b = new int(2);
a = b;
```

or

```
int* a = new int(1);
int* b = new int(2);
delete a;
a = b;
```

I know I shoud use smart pointers, or NOT use them at all as a begginer, my question is more about the memory management in theory.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you don't delete it you have a memory leak.

Comment: Yes, you need to delete a first, otherwise that memory is leaked

Comment: What is meant above, is that after you `a=b`, you have no access to the memory previous pointed to by `a`, so now way to release it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In what cases do I use malloc and/or new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-and-or-new)

Comment: [Should I delete a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42545089/327083)

Comment: [delete vs NULL vs free in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2910587/327083)

Comment: [Do I need to delete a pointer if I haven't assigned it a new value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13709284/327083)

Comment: Thanks for the links, I tried searching it but couldnt find the correct keywords. This is the one that helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13709284/327083

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colloquial speech is a little misleading here. We say "delete the pointer" but more correct would be to say "delete the object pointed to by the pointer". Think of the `int` and the `int*` as two seperate entities (they really are). You can reassign to the pointer as much as you want, thats no problem for the pointer. But if you do

```
int* a = new int(1);  // I
int* b = new int(2);
a = b;
```

Then you lost any reference to the object dynamically created in `I` and you have no way to delete it. Its a memory leak.

Comment: Just would like to comment for op: as far as C++ is concerned, failing to free memory is not an error: the program will yield expected results and behave correctly — that makes it different from, say, a use-after-delete. The question is, as a user of that program, is it acceptable that it slowly eats your memory because it fails to manage its resources correctly?